# How can I manipulate SVG color, as an attached image without the SVG code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'll be getting a different SVG depending on some conditions. So, I can't get the SVG code, the server carries the svg files.

So is there any way to achieve this? I need to change the color dynamically, of whichever svg I get.
This is the code I have

`<svg >
    <img src="rect.svg"width= "150px" height="150px">
</svg>`

Comment: I dont thinks that's a valid svg. Do you have a sample output ? And specificly where the content will be dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

```
fill: currentColor;
```

or

```
fill: red; // Any other color
```

Comment: This doesn't work , sorry